# How to run setup/cleanup only in a pytest script, skipping all testcases in it?

Tags: pytest

Having a pytest script that contains the setup/cleanup and various testcases, and I only need to call the setup/cleanup part in it at one time, but need to call some testcases in it at another time.

So my plan is something like:

```
test1.py PYTEST_ADDOPTS="-k 'not test_abc and not test_def'" SKIP_CLEANUP_ON_SOMETHING=1
test2.py
test1.py
```

Problems is:

1. It doesn't work at all because if no testcase could be collected, the entire test script would be omitted, and the setup/cleanup part doesn't have a chance to kick off.
2. The `PYTEST_ADDOPTS` string would become unbearably long when there are more and more testcase functions in `test1.py`.

Is there a way to skip all the testcases in `test1.py`, so that only the setup/cleanup parts would run?

Comment: As you noticed, setup/cleanup are only run if there are tests collected. Can you elaborate on why you need to run setup/cleanup without anything done in-between? Maybe you are mis-using tests for something else?

Comment: @MrBeanBremen Simply because I only need something in the setup part, and do not need anything else in the script. Also, to duplicate the setup part into another separate script is not desirable.  :(

Comment: I'm still not clear on what you want to achieve - if you don't run any tests, what you need the setup for?

Comment: @MrBeanBremen I only need something in the setup part of `test1.py`, but I need to do something else with some other script after that.